# Regex to include optional newline before a word

Tags: regex, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to formulate a regex that parses the class name from React.js as follows.

Say, this is the class name

```
export interface IStackBarProps
  extends React.AllHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement | HTMLButtonElement | HTMLDivElement | BaseButton | Button> {
```

This is the regex I have so far

```
regex = new RegExp(`^export (interface|(?:const )?enum) ${propsInterfaceOrEnumName}(?: extends .*?)? \\{( |.*[\\r\\n]*)*?\\}`, 'm');
```

It works except that the `extends` being on a new line in the original string causes it to fail.

How can I add an **optional** new line just before the word extends, since some classes could have the word extends on a separate line, and some not?

I have tried a few combinations of `[\\n]*` but haven't been able to get it to match.

Comment: maybe [\s\S]*? instead? I believe that should jump a new line if there is one.

Comment: Try `[\n\r]*` which caters for all flavors of line ending chars (windows, mac and *nix).

Comment: @Bohemian thanks, but same again. I tried doing this, could not get it to compile/transpile. regex = new RegExp(`^export (interface|(?:const )?enum) ${propsInterfaceOrEnumName} ([\n\r]*) (?: extends .*?)? \\{( |.*[\\r\\n]*)*?\\}

Comment: @Ted  thanks, I tried doing this, could not get it to compile/transpile. regex = new RegExp(`^export (interface|(?:const )?enum) ${propsInterfaceOrEnumName} ([\s\S]*) (?: extends .*?)? \\{( |.*[\\r\\n]*)*?\\}

Comment: @user121 you would need `[\\s\\S]`, not `[\s\S]`

Comment: @Nick , could you copy me the entire line, please. I tried this and get a compile error. regex = new RegExp(`^export (interface|(?:const )?enum) ${propsInterfaceOrEnumName}([\\s\\S]*) (?: extends .*?)? \\{( |.*[\\r\\n]*)*?\\}

Comment: This compiles fine for me: `var regex = new RegExp(\`^export (interface|(?:const )?enum) ${propsInterfaceOrEnumName}([\\s\\S]*) (?: extends .*?)? \\{( |.*[\\r\\n]*)*?\\}\`, 'm');`

Comment: @Nick , hmm, tried the same, but does not compile for me. Mine is a .ts file, btw. I tried without the var, and used let
let regex: RegExp | null = null;
regex= "your string above"

Comment: @Nick , sorry, it actually compiles (the error was regarding max characters allowed in a line), however the regex doesn't seem to help.

Comment: @Ted I am past my compilation issues, but the regex does not seem to work

Comment: @Bohemian I am past my compilation issues, but the regex does not seem to work

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/reiggL/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I can see this works on the link you sent me, but it just does not work for me. Here is how my source looks like, for the regex you passed me. https://snag.gy/aDo5kU.jpg